# How to make Adaptive Card as Collective?

Tags: c#, async-await, adaptive-cards, botframework

Name.json:

```json
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Hello ${name}!"
      }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var replyText = PrepareCard.ReadCard("Name.json");
    AdaptiveCardTemplate template = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(replyText);
    var myData = new
    {
        Name = "Matt Hidinger"
    };
    string cardJson = template.Expand(myData);
    var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardJson),
    };


    var Attachments = new List<Attachment>() {
        cardAttachment,
    };

    var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(Attachments);
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
}
```

If I want to add list of name which display like a scrollable. How could I make it? I could able to display one name with one card. So my requirement is, using that one adaptive card I want to add list of names and displays it as scrollable.

Comment: I've never seen an Adaptive Card with a scrollbar. If you have, can you link me to an example? If you haven't, does that mean you're asking about Adaptive Cards extensibility? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/extensibility

Comment: Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: I would like to help you find a solution but I need to understand what it is you're trying to achieve first. Can you answer my questions?

Comment: I will tell you clearly, i want to display flight availability.I have 2 or more flights for the particular destination.Like choice prompt, there will be arrow symbol at right side,when we click it will move on to next choice.In the sameway, i have to display flights using adaptive card, when we click arrow symbol, it will move to next flight.

Comment: I will have dynamic flights data and i can able to render those details in adaptive card.But i can able to create one flight details with one card.i can't make it as list.

Comment: Are you using Teams? Would you like to display each flight in its own card and then display all the cards as a carousel? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#example-carousel-collection

Comment: Thank you so much, i got output based on your solution

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use multiple Adaptive Cards with the carousel attachment layout.